# what am i lacking on mysql select query?

Tags: mysql

what am I doing is checking if the `signatoryid` from the user input has the lowest level from the table which `status = 1` and group by `tracknum`

so if the input of the user is not the lowest level on that tracknum it will not give output. but if it has the lowest level. it will give output

so far this is my query this works for `signatoryid`-`LHPL004`

but doesnt work for other signatory id like `LHPL003` and so on. so whats lack with mysql code? thank you

```
   SELECT `tracknum`, `signatoryid`, `signatorylevel`, `status`
from tble_transaction 
where `status` = "1" and signatoryid = "LHPL004" and `signatorylevel` = (select MIN(`signatorylevel`) from tble_transaction where `status`="1"  )
```

[image]

this is my expected output when i use LHPL003 as signatory ID

[image]

it didnt print out the one with tracknum DOC009 with signatoryID because the level of LHPL003 is 3 and on that tracknum DOC009 there is someone with lower level whose status is still 1 not 0

Comment: Your `signatoryid` with value `LHPL004` doesn't hold the minimum value of `signatorylevel`

Comment: `signatoryid = "LHPL005"` holds the minimum `signatorylevel` value which is `1`

Comment: Please show your expected output. May be we can help you out then.@Audrey

Comment: but signatory with value LHPL003 doesnt give me output. it must give me output with with tracknumber DOC010  because on that group of tracknum the LHPL003 has the lowest level whose status = 1

Comment: The subquery `select MIN(signatorylevel) from tble_transaction where status = "1"` returns `MIN(signatorylevel)` *for the entire table.* Specifically, it returns the value `2`, and only signatoryid `LHPL004` has a record with that `signatorylevel`, according to your sample data.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax so how can i use the tracknum of the first query and pass the tracknum value to the subquery using where?

Comment: @1000111 i already updated the question sir. with the desired output thank you

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax i understand what you meant sir and i think thats the problem with mysql code. so how can i pass the tracknum of the sql to the sql subquery so that. the subquery will query the table in each tracknum. and nut getting the minimum of the whole table?

Comment: I think a correlated subquery would do it, but it's going to take me a while to remember how to write one. It would help if you could describe more generally what you want your query to achieve.

Comment: what i want to do sir is show only the ones with the lowest level on each tracknum which status = 1. i can't explain it clearly because english is not my language and im not good at it

Comment: Let me check if I understand your requirement :**you want the corresponding row for each `tracknum` having the minimum `signatorylevel`.**@Audrey

Comment: yes sir. and it must be group by tracknum please help me. i realy need to finish this until tomorrow. its been three days i have been searching for a solution

Comment: Please check the query in my answer@Audrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Probably you want the corresponding row for each `tracknum` having the **minimum** `signatorylevel` with `status=1`.

This assumption is based on your comment:

> what i want to do sir is show only the ones with the lowest level on
>   each tracknum which status = 1.

---

---

The following query might suffice :

```
SELECT 
tble_transaction.*
FROM tble_transaction
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   tracknum,
   MIN(signatorylevel) min_signatorylevel
  FROM tble_transaction
  WHERE `status` = "1"
  GROUP BY tracknum
) AS t
ON tble_transaction.tracknum = t.tracknum AND 
tble_transaction.signatorylevel = t.min_signatorylevel;
```

---

---

**Output:**

```
tracknum    signatoryid   datesigned    datereceived     signed   status    signatorylevel
DOC009       LHPL004      0/0/0000       0/0/0000       Released    1           2
DOC010       LHPL003      0/0/0000       0/0/0000       Released    1           3
```

---

---

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eb46/1/0)

---

---

**Note:**

Look, in your sample data although minimum `signatorylevel`is 1 for both `tracknum` **DOC009** AND **DOC010** but they have `status = 0`. So they won't appear in the result.

---

---

Answer (score 1):

The subquery

```
select MIN(signatorylevel) from tble_transaction where status = "1"
```

returns `MIN(signatorylevel)` for the entire table. Specifically, it returns the value `2`, and only `signatoryid` **`LHPL004`** has a record with that `signatorylevel`, according to your sample data.

I *think* this should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
SELECT t1.tracknum, t1.signatoryid, t1.signatorylevel, t1.`status`
  FROM tble_transaction t1
  WHERE t1.`status` = "1"
    AND t1.signatoryid = "LHPL004"
    AND t1.signatorylevel =
      (SELECT MIN(t2.signatorylevel)
        FROM tble_transaction t2
        WHERE t2.`status` = "1"
          AND t2.tracknum = t1.tracknum
      );
```

This solution uses a correlated subquery, where the subquery is run once for each record returned by the outer query. (See the last `AND` subclause of the subquery's `WHERE` clause.)

Any correlated subquery can be rewritten as a join, and vice versa, so (assuming your DBMS has a good optimizer) the only significant difference between my solution and 1000111's is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Only LHPL004 will generate an output because it is the only one with the lowest signatorylevel and status of 1. Anything else including LHPL003 has not the lowest signatorylevel so it wont output anything and thus your code is working correctly.

Comment: you can take a look @ Darwin von Corax last  comment .. which is so clear to read and understand quickly than yours